# What if I use would have rather than would be in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

CONTEXT:

> If not for you, my sky would fall.

This is a part of lyrics from "not for you" song. So, can I use " would have fallen" in place of simply "would"? Would the meaning be same or not if I do this replacement?

Comment: Suppose you'd just performed [the Heimlich Maneuver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CgtIgSyAiU) on a choking fellow-diner in a restaurant. They'd say *Thanks! If not for you I would have died!* (not *...I would die*) because it's obvious that at time of speaking that "risk of death" is in the ***past***. For your context the singer almost certainly wants to convey that his life ***still*** depends on his relationship with the addressee, so he'd use "hypothetical present/future tense". That's to say it's just an ordinary ***past*** or ***present/future*** distinction.

Comment: "Would fall" is a potential *future* event.  "Would have fallen" is a conditional *past* event.  So the lyric would be slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) If . . . my sky would fall.
>   2) If . . . my sky would have fallen.

These do not mean the same thing.

- 1) *would fall* speaks of a non-past consequence. The condition *If not for you* is understood to be an unrealized event, something like "If you were not present/in my life" or "If you did not support me". Since the condition is unrealized, the consequence is not realized either; consequently the condition is understood as a hypothetical future event.
- 2) *would have fallen* speaks of a past consequence, and the condition is understood to be an event which was not realized in the past. Again, since the condition was not realized, the consequence was not realized either; consequently the condition is understood as a counterfactual past event.

Comment: I'm a bit iffy about ***If not for X*** referring to *a hypothetical **future** event*. It seems to me in that construction ***X*** is pragmatically required to be something that ***was** or **is** present / true / happening* before / at time of speaking (the "hypothetical" allusion being to a possible alternative past/present where it wasn't/isn't true). I've tried thinking of contexts where it could apply to something in the future *(If not for my old age pension I will [would?] be destitute in retirement),* but it just doesn't seem to work so well.

Comment: @FumbleFingers If it is not true/actualized now it can only be true/actualized in the future.

Comment: It's a *hypothetical,* which doesn't necessarily have any direct relationship with past, present, or future. *If not for gravity you would go spinning off into space* in no way implies that gravity either did or will cease to exist, past or future.